# How to set threshold in ImageJ for quantifying relative fluorescence?

Tags: fluorescent-microscopy, imaging, imagej

I have taken images from two different samples that have uptaken EdU during DNA synthesis (S-phase). The experiment setup is to find which condition had uptaken more EdU. Therefore I am detecting EdU with fluorescent to be able to quantify them in two conditions and compare them. The images are taken under same exposure. However in ImageJ when I want to adjust threshold I am not sure if I need to have the same threshold for both images or they can be different? Any tips are appreciated and let me know if I need to provide more info.

cheers!

Comment: Presumably your image is either a blot, or of cells. You're going to use some software to measure the density of the blots or cells - what software? [You can use ImageJ](http://www.med.umn.edu/starrlab/prod/groups/med/@pub/@med/@starrlab/documents/content/med_content_370494.html) if you haven't another way. Either way you need to have the original images in a lossless format for the quantification. I think if you adjust levels and click 'apply', you stand to change pixel values.

I've used an old program called OptiQuant to get numbers, and separately adjusted the images for ease of viewing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding software use are off topic on BioSE. I understand the need of bio researchers for protocols, but your question is still off topic

Comment: @Raoul you have a good point but image j framework is very specific to biology. I think seeing these sorts of questions here is within scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to have the same threshold for both images because you want to make comparison between them. Do you have a control condition (the condition which is not supposed to uptake EdU)? if yes, then use it to set your threshold and keep the same threshold for the tests conditions. If not, you can either make a experiment control, or select a region of interest (ROI) in one of your 2 tests where there is no coloration (no uptaking of EdU) and set the threshold in this ROI. 
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to normalize both images to the background. This can be done in many softwares including photoshop.

When I was learning this starting to do it with something more simple like SDS page protein bands helped me a lot. The principles are the same you are still subtracting background. Look at this tutorial:

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JlR5v-DsTds

However, when analyzing intensity values in fluorescent microscopy the most important parameter is area of your analysis. This needs to be an objectively applied as much as possible, and that can be by increasing the number of replicates whose area you analyze. Your going to look at pixel intensities for many many cells and average those intensities. Using the imagej cell counter plug-in is helpful to see how to determine cell area.